# $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}$, how to estimate the order of $a_{n}$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

We know $\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{2n}} \rightarrow 1, n \rightarrow +\infty$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}}，a_{1}>0 $
Maybe the idea to compare $a_{n}^{2}$ to $2n$ comes from the fact that the corresponding differential equation $$x'(t)=\frac{1}{x(t)}$$ is solved by $$x^2(t)=2t+x^2(0)$$ 
We see $x'(t)$ as $a_{n+1}-a_{n}$，and we can get $a_{n}^{2} \sim 2n+\text{const}，n \rightarrow +\infty$，then we can guess $\frac{a_{n}^{2}}{2n} \rightarrow 1，n \rightarrow +\infty$ ，then we go on

But what if it's $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}$ with $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}$?

I already know $\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{2\text{ln}n}} \rightarrow 1, n \rightarrow +\infty$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}，a_{1}>0 $ ，but I don't know **WHY** we compare $a_{n}^{2}$ to $2\text{ln}n$，is there a equation or something like Taylor Series?

I also know $\frac{\text{ln}n}{\text{lnln}n}(\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{2\text{ln}n}}-1) \rightarrow \frac{1}{4}, n \rightarrow +\infty$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}，a_{1}>0 $，so I'm sure that we can estimate  the order of $a_{n}$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}$ .I just don't know how

Then I suppose that  $\frac{n}{\text{ln}n}(\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{2n}}-1) \rightarrow a, n \rightarrow +\infty$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}}，a_{1}>0 $.

Well，it looks like the above formula，isn't it? It's a guess. I don't know what number the limit is. I don't even know if it's ture for what I'm doing.

Thank you very much

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. If you already know that $\frac{a_{n}}{\sqrt{2\text{ln}n}} \to 1$ then what are you asking for?

Comment: @Martin R I’m so sorry if I didn't express it clearly. I'm not asking the approach——using O‘Stolz theorem,etc.Let me change the question——“$a_{1} ＞0,a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{S_{n}}$,try to estimate the order of $a_{n}$”.Yes,we all know $a_{n}=\sqrt{2\text{ln}n}+o(1)$ now.  But how do you know the result when you first do it. Like what I said before,the differential equation as a trigger inspires me to estimate the order of $a_{n}$ with $a_{n+1}=a_{n}+\frac{1}{a_{n}}$. So what I want is the trigger. Hope it's better .Thank you again.